# OpenCV can't get max. fps

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, yolo

I'm reading the stream of a caputercard into OpenCV, but unfortunately I can't reach the FPS limit of the capturecard with this approach. The capturecard is an AverMedia Live Gamer Ultra (FPS limit at 120). When using the Avermedia studio tool I can receive 120FPS but when reading the stream in OpenCV it's only around 70-40FPS. My Code looks as follows:

```
import time
import cv2
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32ui
import numpy as np


class Speedtest:
    hwnd = None
    cropped_x = 0
    cropped_y = 0
    offset_x = 0
    offset_y = 0
    capture = None
    sct_img = None

    def __init__(self):
        
        #Setting Device
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        # setting resolution of capture card
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)

        # setting FPS of capture card
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 120)

        #this does return 120.000
        print("fps: ", self.capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

        # reduce input lag by limiting buffer size
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)

        #changing codec
        codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'j', 'p', 'g')
        print(self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, codec))

    def run(self):
        # used to record the time when we processed last frame
        prev_frame_time = 0

        # used to record the time at which we processed current frame
        new_frame_time = 0

        while True:
            start = time.perf_counter()

            ret, self.sct_img = self.capture.read()

            prev_frame_time = new_frame_time
            new_frame_time = time.perf_counter()

            # calculating framerates
            fps = 1 / (new_frame_time - prev_frame_time)

            # casting fps to int to remove comma and string to display
            fps = int(fps)
            print("fps: ", fps)

            cv2.imshow('Image', np.array(self.sct_img))
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break


speedtest = Speedtest()
speedtest.run()
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to remove imshow and waitKey and measure the fps again? If you reach max fps then, you should parallelize capturing and rendering, e.g. by using different threads.

Comment: And for time measurement use the average fps of e.g. 5 seconds instead of measuring single frame time.

Comment: @Micka Thanks a lot for your answer. I just tried to comment out imshow and waitKey and it does indeed increase the framerate by about 15-30fps. I tried a different capturing method yesterday and I noticed that the biggest problem is not even the fps I get using the capturecard, but the input delay. There's about 0.5 seconds of input delay when using the capturecard in opencv, but when checking it out in the AverMedia Application there's no delay at all. I already tried to reduce the interal buffer using CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE to reduce the latency but unfortunately without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Internal buffers are a problem in opencv. I would recommend to use the manufacturer SDKs for your camera directly, if available, which will raise additional work but you will have more control. However I'm quite sure that you will be able to decrease delay if you make sure that you capture the whole framerate. If processing time reduces the framerate, use threading to always capture the latest frame as fast as possible and only process the last captured frame.